# Can I use a Maven plugin (enunciate) in Gradle?

Tags: maven, plugins, ant, gradle, enunciate

I have a maven plugin called enunciate that generates nice API documentation. I'd rather use Gradle as my build tool but it looks like it's limited in this aspect or maybe I just don't know how to use it.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a maven plugin (enunciate) in gradle somehow? Do I have to write an ant script and call that? So far I can't find a gradle example for enunciate so I'm guessing it's not supported?

Comment: Sounds like a Gradle plugin for Enunciate might be worth looking into. Why don't you consider opening up a [JIRA request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE)?

Comment: Hi Ryan! I don't have an account for JIRA to post a request but I would like to. I'm new to enunciate and am trying to use it for a Spring 3 project with both rest and jax-ws services. I'd like to use gradle instead of maven since gradle is how we're building the project.

Comment: Saw the signup in the dashboard so I was able to submit [http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-815](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-815)

Comment: FYI, we ended up sticking to maven. It's not as easy as gradle but we found there were even more plugins we needed that supported maven but not gradle.

Comment: Any info on the gradle plugin? This is the only thing keeping our team from migrating to gradle once and for all.

Comment: Here's the enhancement request https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/issues/67.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't use a Maven plugin as-is in Gradle; you'll have to port it to a Gradle plugin. How difficult this is depends on how many Maven APIs the plugin is using. Another strategy might be to call into Maven via Gradle's `Exec` task.

Comment: can you please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911102/how-to-execute-maven-plugins-from-gradle-without-having-maven-and-java-installed

Answer (score 7):

As of October 2015, a Gradle plugin for Enunciate is available.

https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate-gradle