# Using custom maven plugin in gradle project

Tags: gradle, maven-plugin

I developed custom maven plugin using java 5 annotations and I want to use that plugin in gradle project but I am not getting any useful stuff on internet even after lots of googling could you please let me know how to use custom maven plugin in project build with gradle?
Thanks and Regards,
Mahendra Tonape.

Comment: Gradle cannot run Maven plugins directly.

Comment: @Ben : could you please suggest me any ways to run maven plugins in gradle?

Comment: You're best bet is to write a Gradle plugin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a Maven plugin (enunciate) in Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642990/can-i-use-a-maven-plugin-enunciate-in-gradle)