# How to execute maven plugins from gradle without having maven and java installed

Tags: java, maven, gradle, plugins, build.gradle

I need to execute a `maven plugin` on a system that does not have both `maven` and `java` installed and installing both of them on the system is not an option. While searching for the ways, I found out that by using [gradle](https://gradle.org/) we can build executable binaries that does not even require `gradle` to get executed, which perfectly fits my situation :) . Is there any way to execute `maven` plugins by using `gradle`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Java is required for Maven and for Gradle too.

You can use [Maven Wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) exactly like with Gradle.

Execute this command in project directory (this creates executable script like in gradle)

```
mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
```

To invoke this project without maven installed use:

```
./mvnw GOAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Maven and Gradle require java to be installed. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

Comment: yeah, Java is need for compilation, but does `java` is needed to run a native binary created from `gradle`

Comment: AFAIK, gradle will only create executable jar files for java, not native binaries. This seems to be in line with their documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/native_software.html

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is a build system. You can build anything with it, including native binaries.

And yes, you can call Maven Plugins from Gradle, as Maven Plugins are written in Java and Gradle is based on Groovy and thus on Java.

But both facts have nothing to do with each other.

You can of course also use Gradle (or any other build system including manually stuffing things together) to build a distributable that includes a Java runtime environment. But then Java is, as said, shipped with your result. You cannot run Java code without having Java around, besides porting the Java code to something else like C++ that compiles to a native binary.

Yes, you can also call Java code from native code if you do some glueing, but no, also this will not work without having Java around, because that's the way Java works.

Comment: You can call Maven Plugins from Gradle??

Comment: Why not? Maven plugins are nothing else than Java classes, so you can call them. It is usually nicer to search an according Gradle plugin that fits nice into the DSL, but it should probably work nontheless.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Have you actually tried it? I was surprised because when I searched the web it seems that it said everywhere that it was not possible

Comment: Of course not, imho it is ridiculous to do so and certainly ugly. But I don't know why it shouldn't work, it is a Java class. You cannot use it like you use it in Maven by just saying `apply this Maven plugin` which is what you found, but using the Java classes that back the Maven class should be possible. There should just usually be no reason to go the ugly and cumbersome way. If it is a custom plugin, better rewrite it for Gradle, will be much better to use. If it is a 3rd party plugin, search a replacement or ask them to provide a Gradle plugin. What plugin are you wishing to use.

Comment: I was looking at teavm maven plugin, but I managed to make the equivalent gradle plugin work

Comment: I am not entirely sure that the fact that they are java classes would be enough to run them in Gradle though. Since they are plugins, probably some maven logic is required to make them work

Comment: I didn't say it is easy or nice, I just say it should be possible and if it is that you generate a temporary Maven build and execute Maven on it. But that would just be a very last resort.